# why doesn't my gaussian pdf integrate to one?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

normal pdf:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy

def gaussian(x, mu = 0, sigma = 1):
  return 1/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi*sigma)) * np.exp(-(x-mu)**2 / (0.5*sigma)**2)
```

integrate over entire support:

```py
scipy.integrate.quad(gaussian, -np.inf, np.inf)
```

returns

```
(0.3535533905932738, 1.4635936470160148e-11)
```

I know I messed up somewhere in the pdf but i've been starting at it for an hour and i can't see it

Comment: The denominator of the exponential is wrong. It should be simply `2*sigma` (assuming `sigma` is the variance).

Answer (score 1):

Your gaussian function is incorrect. It should be:

```
def gaussian(x, mu = 0, sigma = 1):
  return (1/(sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi))) * np.exp((-(x-mu)**2) / (2 * sigma ** 2))
```